# jQuery, how to correctly find element type of a parent element in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I'm trying to find "checkbox" inside the parent element table. Below, my HTML code has a checkbox input with an ID of "selectall". Using jQuery, when "selectall" is changed, I want to, skip back to the parent element table and find the first mention of "checkbox" as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Datetime</th>
        <th>Reading</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Gate</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        // while loop, fetch the SQL result as an array
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            // echo the database data
            echo '<tr><td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check-class" value="' . $row['ID'] . '"></td>';
            echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['datetime'] . "</td><td>" . $row['reading'] . "</td><td>" . $row['status'] . "</td><td>" . $row['gate'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    // have a check all button and delete input -->
    ?>

    <tr valign="middle">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>Check All
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">
            <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
// declare select all checkbox
$('#selectall').change(function() {
    // declare other checkboxes
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox');
    // if checked, set to all true
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
    }
    // else, set all to false
    else {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    }
});});
```

The purpose is that, for every row in my sql query, I return the fields to the HTML table, each with a checkbox. My table is coded so that for every record, a checkbox appears on the same table row, thus allowing me to select that checkbox (or multiple of) in a different SQL statement later to DELETE such record(s) from the SQL table.

Thus, using javascript, I'm trying to use a separate checkbox that, once checked, checks all the other checkboxes. If that makes sense.

I had a working example before, but it was a mess. I wrapped everything within php tags and echoed all the necessary HTML tags (obviously a bad idea), hence the change now. But it did work before:

**Before:**

```
echo '<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">';
    echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
        echo "<tr><th>#</th><th>ID</th><th>datetime</th><th>reading</th><th>status</th><th>gate</th></tr>";
        // while loop, fetch the SQL result as an array
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            // echo the database data
            echo '<tr><td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check-class" value="' . $row['ID'] . '"></td>';
            echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['datetime'] . "</td><td>" . $row['reading'] . "</td><td>" . $row['status'] . "</td><td>" . $row['gate'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        // have a check all button and delete input
        echo '<tr valign="middle"><td><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>Check All</td><td align="center" colspan="5"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td></tr>';
    echo "</table>";
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
// declare select all checkbox
$('#selectall').change(function() {
    // declare other checkboxes
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
    // if checked, set to all true
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
    }
    // else, set all to false
    else {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    }
});});
```

Please advise.

**EDIT (Converted HTML paste):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flood Sensor Web Interface</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/checkall.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttoncontrol.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/paginate.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Flood Sensor Web Interface</h1>
    <p>This web interface will display all the table data. To
    delete, check the relevant checkbox (or multiple checkboxes)
    and press the delete button.</p>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Datetime</th>
        <th>Reading</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Gate</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox"
          class="check-class" value="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2014-12-03_18:24:52</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Safe</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox"
                class="check-class" value="3">
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>2014-12-03_18:24:55</td>
                  <td>13443</td>
                  <td>Safe</td>
                  <td>Open</td>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox"
                      class="check-class" value="4">
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2014-12-03_18:24:58</td>
                        <td>35656</td>
                        <td>Caution</td>
                        <td>Open</td>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <input name="checkbox[]"
                            type="checkbox" class="check-class"
                            value="6">
                              <td>6</td>
                              <td>2014-12-03_18:25:04</td>
                              <td>57085</td>
                              <td>Danger</td>
                              <td>Closed</td>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <input name="checkbox[]"
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  class="check-class" value="7">
                                    <td>7</td>
                                    <td>2014-12-03_18:25:07</td>
                                    <td>28823</td>
                                    <td>Caution</td>
                                    <td>Open</td>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <input name="checkbox[]"
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        class="check-class"
                                        value="8">
                                          <td>8</td>
                                          <td>
                                          2014-12-03_18:25:10</td>
                                          <td>65535</td>
                                          <td>Danger</td>
                                          <td>Closed</td>
                                          <!-- have a check all button and delete input -->
                                          <tr valign="middle">
                                            <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox"
                                            id="selectall" />Check
                                            All</td>
                                            <td align="center"
                                            colspan="5">
                                              <input name="delete"
                                              type="submit"
                                              id="delete"
                                              value="Delete">
                                                <a href="https://agent.electricimp.com/ABCDEFG?report=0">
                                                Disable Database
                                                Reporting</a>
                                                <br />
                                                <a href="https://agent.electricimp.com/ABCDEFG?report=1">
                                                Enable Database
                                                Reporting</a>
                                                <br />
                                                <a href="https://agent.electricimp.com/ABCDEFG?gate=0">
                                                Override OFF
                                                Barrier</a>
                                                <br />
                                                <a href="https://agent.electricimp.com/ABCDEFG?gate=1">
                                                Override ON
                                                Barrier</a>
                                                <br />
                                                <a href="https://agent.electricimp.com/ABCDEFG?lamp=0">
                                                Override OFF
                                                Lamp</a>
                                                <br />
                                                <a href="https://agent.electricimp.com/ABCDEFG?lamp=1">
                                                Override ON
                                                Lamp</a>
                                              </input>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </input>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </input>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </input>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </input>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </input>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is it that the code stops/breaks? Try to `console.log()` different places/objects.

Comment: @bvx89 hi, I tried to insert "console.log()" inbetween lines of the javascript file. But I'm not entirely sure how to view the output for the debugging purposes. Just to clarify, when I check the checkbox of id "selectall", all the checkboxes above should be checked.

Here's a screenshot to represent the output: http://i.imgur.com/E4MbF8t.jpg

Comment: not clear what the problem is. create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates your issue

Comment: @charlietfl http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=a5EoHMQAUu Here is a demo that replicates the issue. I couldn't include php, so I omitted that out.

Comment: there's no code at all in that fiddle. Also, for client side problems you shouldn't include php anyway, just source html which is easy to get from browser

Comment: @charlietfl Apologies, I'm not familiar with jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/revxaisks/wp7m8bw7/ This is the current code I have now (same as above example) where I ignored PHP data and simply used dummy data for value instead of echoing $row['value']

Comment: You need to set the jquery library on the side

Comment: Please be mindful of the Q&A format - don't alter your question just because it's solved, that's what answers (and the accept mechanism) are for. It's also not usually a good idea to include words like "edit" or "update" in your question, because you're just duplicating the built-in edit summary in a way which will confuse future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are wanting much easier.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectall").on("change", function() {
  $.event.trigger("mycheck", {checked: $(this).prop("checked")});
});

$(".check-class").on("mycheck", function(e, data) {
  $(this).prop("checked", data.checked);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, is this method for the new html code without having to use php to echo out all the HTML elements? The reason I need to separate all the HTML and PHP is because of other website functionality I need to do, it makes my project alot simpler (and by convention it's not sensible to echo HTML via PHP anyway?) I don't have form data in my revised code.

Comment: This should work for either.  When selectall is changed, it fires the mycheck custom event with it's checked property as a parameter in the event.  All of the other checkboxes are subscribers to that event and will set themselves to the checked property passed in.

Comment: If you could add the actual relevant html rather than the php code it would be much easier to test this on jsfiddle

Comment: I just tried your javascript code and took your suggestion. Hopefully I understood what you meant. Apologies, I'm new to jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/revxaisks/1zx2ww54/

Comment: Did you get it to work?  I noticed you added the check-class, updating answer to reflect the new selector

Comment: Hmmm, in my script file, it doesn't work. For reference purposes, I attached the <?php ?> that wraps around the table rows into the CSS table for reference. http://jsfiddle.net/revxaisks/vw6oc4x6/1/

Comment: Please check my document ready call: http://jsfiddle.net/revxaisks/vw6oc4x6/2/ Still no change. Script files have been replaced and uploaded to server. Tried multiple browsers, no luck. On source inspect it shows new changes. Files have been replaced.

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating how to pass jQuery in http://jsfiddle.net/ccav/vw6oc4x6/5/

Comment: Silly question. (But probably the root of the issue so far) Do I use '<script type="text/javascript" src="SCRIPTNAME.js"></script>' and copy the jsfiddle code to the script named SCRIPTNAME.js (preferably), or code it inside the HTML file. PS: Thanks very much for your help and patience. I have absolutely no jquery background. (Copying it into a separate script file and declaring it so far hasn't worked) jquery library: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Yes, put it into another file and load it with a script tag, make sure the jquery script tag is above it in your page so jQuery is loaded.

Comment: This? http://i.imgur.com/VyaV9bE.png Still nothing I'm afraid. =( Also added full converted HTML code if it helps (after php processing)

Comment: do you have an url, want to see what is actually hitting the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66173/discussion-between-chris-caviness-and-revxaisks).

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue in the demo code is using `parent()` but the parent of your checkbox is a `td` not a `table` so you aren't reaching far enough up the DOM.

I suggest using `closest()` (as in code shown in question) instead

Try this:

```
$(function () {        
    $('#selectall').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);          
    });
});
```

See following API docs:

**[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

**[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1zx2ww54/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/revxaisks/vw6oc4x6/2/

@Chris Caviness solved the problem. Firstly, check the revised javascript code.

Secondly, like I mentioned in the top post, use an older 1.8.3 script file, then just use the standard

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

in order to wrap the script. Save it as SCRIPTNAME.js and then declare it in the HTML after the library declaration (important!)

My problem was I was using the newer 1.9.1 jQuery library which handled data differently.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Found this plugin which will restore global events to jQuery >= 1.9.  https://github.com/mmikowski/jquery.event.gevent